# Bundler needs to be installed for each gemset with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

Every time I create a new project and attempt to run `bundle` I am hitting this type of error:

```
funkdified@funktop ~/rails_projects $ cd blog
ruby-2.2.2 - #gemset created /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@blog
ruby-2.2.2 - #generating blog wrappers..........
funkdified@funktop ~/rails_projects/blog $ bundle
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried running `rvm @global do gem install bundler` but this is not working either. Before I can bundle, each time, I need to run `gem install bundler` first.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. Once you have installed bundler within one gemset, you can use that gemset each time you create a new project.

First,

```
rvm gemset list_all   # will list all the gemset under all the ruby versions you have installed
```

For example, if you have a gemset named `foo` under ruby version 2.0.0, and this gemset has already get bundler installed, then each time you create a new project, you can always type this `rvm` command to use that gemset.

```
rvm use 2.2.0@foo
```